# Jenkins - Publish Over CIFS Plugin error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using this Publish over CIFS Plugin and I contiinous get an error, even though the copy succeeds. What I'm trying to do is to copy all the contents of a build results directory, all all it's assets, to the remove host. However I get an error message that I can't explain, and the on-line help is failing me.
On the Transfers Section I have only 1 block and this is the setup

```
Source files:  build/123.456/**
Remove prefix: build/
Remote directory: builds/this_release/Latest/
```

Below are the error messages I get.

```
CIFS: Connecting from host [my-host]
CIFS: Connecting with configuration [to-host] ...
CIFS: Disconnecting configuration [to-host] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [A Transfer Set must contain Source files - if you really want to include everything, set Source files to **/ or **\]
Build step 'Send build artifacts to a windows share' changed build result to UNSTABLE
```

What I don't understand is that files under the 'build/123.456/', and sub-directories, get copied as I wanted but still I get an error. Any suggestions on how to correct that ? I've tried removing the '**' and it still works, but I still get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I've found the reason for my error.
I had a second (empty) Transfer Set defined on my job, with no fields filled in
This Set was the reason for the error message.